# How to get absolute path to app in Electron app

Tags: electron

I use Electron to build my app.
I want to load data from zip unpack it to folder file and show it to user.

I decompress data and then open window since its html it should work fine.

However i see that `app.getAppPath()` on dev mode is giving me example path `D:\elektron` but when i build up path is different `D:elektron\resources\app` how to solve this ?